# Duplicate entry […] for key 'PRIMARY' via add new record in many-to-many relation query builder

Tags: many-to-many, typeorm

try to append some categories to a post entity, category and post entity has a many-to-many relationship.

however, if there is some category has exisit,then "ER_DUP_ENTRY: Duplicate entry ... for key 'PRIMARY'" would be occured

looks there is no method like "orIgnore" in the RelationQueryBuilder.

how to solve this situation?

```
await getConnection()
.createQueryBuilder()
.relation(Post, "categories")
.of({postId})
.add(['exisitCategoryId1','newCategoryId2']);
```

Comment: did you find a solution for that?